# How to solve "NoSuchMethodError: The method 'findRenderObject' was called on null" error?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout, qr-code, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to save a QR image and add sharing optionality for that, but while doing so I'm facing with this "findRenderObject was called on null" object.

How can I solve this error? This is the code below

**GenerateQr.dart**

```
import 'package:attendee/services/database.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:qr_flutter/qr_flutter.dart';
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:attendee/constants.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

class GeneratePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => GeneratePageState();
}

class GeneratePageState extends State<GeneratePage> {
  String qrData =
      "https://github.com/neon97"; // already generated qr code when the page opens
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  String subject;

  GlobalKey globalKey = new GlobalKey();

  final CollectionReference student_details =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('students');
  final CollectionReference tutor_details =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("tutors");

  String timeString;
  bool _validate = false;
  // String formattedDate = DateFormat('kk:mm:ss \n EEE d MMM').format(now);

  static const double _topSectionTopPadding = 50.0;
  static const double _topSectionBottomPadding = 20.0;
  static const double _topSectionHeight = 50.0;

  void _getTime() {
    final String formattedDateTime =
        DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd \n kk:mm:ss').format(DateTime.now()).toString();
    //DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').toString();
    setState(() {
      timeString = formattedDateTime;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer t) => _getTime());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var numberOfClasses;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('QR Code Generator'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.share),
            onPressed: _captureAndSharePng,
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              QrImage(
                //plce where the QR Image will be shown
                data: qrData,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 40.0,
              ),
              Text(
                "New QR Link Generator",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
              ),
              TextField(
                controller: qrdataFeed,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "SUBJECT-anything",
                  errorText:
                      _validate ? "Please enter in Sub-Date format!" : null,
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(40, 20, 40, 0),
                  child: MaterialButton(
                    minWidth: double.infinity,
                    height: 60,
                    onPressed: () async {
                      qrdataFeed.text
                              .contains(RegExp(r'^[a-zA-Z]*\-[a-zA-Z]*$'))
                          ? _validate = false
                          : _validate = true;
                      if (qrdataFeed.text.isEmpty) {
                        //a little validation for the textfield
                        if (!mounted) return;
                        setState(() {
                          qrData = "";
                        });
                      } else {
                        int index = qrdataFeed.text.indexOf('-');
                        subject = qrdataFeed.text.substring(0, index);
                        print("Subject name is $subject");
                        String user = isTutor ? "tutors" : "students";
                        String uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid;
                        numberOfClasses = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                            .collection(user)
                            .doc(uid)
                            .get()
                            .then((value) {
                          return value.data()['numberOfClasses'];
                        });
                        String rollno = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                            .collection(user)
                            .doc(uid)
                            .get()
                            .then((value) {
                          return value.data()['rollno'];
                        });
                        print('$numberOfClasses is printed pehle');
                        await DatabaseService().attendance(rollno);

                        setState(() {
                          qrData = qrdataFeed.text;
                          scanned = true;
                          print('done');
                          numberOfClasses += 1; //idhar se dekhke
                          print('$numberOfClasses is printed');
                        });
                        await tutor_details.doc(uid).set(
                            {'numberOfClasses': numberOfClasses},
                            SetOptions(merge: true));
                      }
                    },
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        side: BorderSide(
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
                    child: Text(
                      "Generate QR",
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontSize: 18),
                    ),
                  )),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  final qrdataFeed = TextEditingController();
  Future<void> _captureAndSharePng() async {
    try {
      RenderRepaintBoundary boundary =
          globalKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
      print(boundary);
      var image = await boundary.toImage();
      ByteData byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png);
      Uint8List pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();

      final tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
      final file = await new File('${tempDir.path}/image.png').create();
      await file.writeAsBytes(pngBytes);

      final channel = const MethodChannel('channel:me.attendee.share/share');
      channel.invokeMethod('shareFile', 'image.png');
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter appear The method 'findRenderObject' was called on null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61241536/flutter-appear-the-method-findrenderobject-was-called-on-null)

Comment: yes mostly similar case

Comment: So did it help you solve your error? If so, would you kindly create an answer with the approach that was useful in your use case for future readers to see how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The error is here:

```
RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = globalKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
```

Try changing **globalKey.currentContext** with **context** and see if the error is solved

Bye :D

Comment: No its throwing error as we cant use globalKey.context

Comment: Yup what I told you

Comment: sorry it didnt solved the problem..any other way?